# Is there a way to click div container wrapped react-router Link component?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a problem in my react project and I tried to describe this problem below. I wrapped all the component with react-router Link. In some parts of code, I need this Link for navigation, but I need to disable Link component for navigation and use inner div with onClick action elsewhere.

```
<Link to={`/somewhere}`}>
  <div onClick={this.handleClick}>
    ....some other div container...
  <div>
<Link>
```

I hope I explained my suffering. Waiting for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

extract the JSX inside of `Link` into its own component and render conditionally

```
// InnerComponent.jsx

const InnerComponent = ({isLink, to}) => {
   
   const handleClick = () => {
     // your onClick handler
   }

   const InnerJsx = (
     <div onClick={ isLink ? () => {} : handleClick } >
       {...Your JSX...}
     </div>
   )
   
   return (
     isLink ? <Link to={to}>{InnerJsx}</Link> : InnerJsx
   )
}

export default InnerComponent;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, my code is working now.